# Facebook auto like and auto comments for a bot

Tags: .net, vb.net, facebook-like, bots, facebook-comments

need source code for facebook auto like and auto comments using vb.net, so far we have created only upto auto login.

our source code for logging in is:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles fb_button.Click
    Dim fb_button As String = Nothing
    For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.All
        If InStr(element.Id, "u_0_b") Then
            fb_button = element.Id
        End If
    Next
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pass").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)

    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(fb_button).InvokeMember("click")

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.facebook.com/")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles fb_button.Click
    Dim fb_button As String = Nothing
    For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.All
        If InStr(element.Id, "u_0_b") Then
            fb_button = element.Id
        End If
    Next
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pass").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)

    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(fb_button).InvokeMember("click")

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.facebook.com/")
End Sub
```